# How to remove shortcut from menu?

Tags: git, uninstallation

I uninstalled git from my computer (windows 10).

But still when I right-click on any folder
I see in the menu that opens:
'Git GUI Here' and 'Git Bash Here'.
screenshot attached.  [menue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFeEt.png)

My question is: how to remove it?

And how do I know I'm removing all files
Related to git.

I want my computer to be "clean" from Git

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's not git component, but git tool, independant from git. I guess it is Git SCM, you have to uninstall it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before choosing which path to take to complete your task, always backup the registry before starting, and double check the path of the registry key at the bottom of the registry editor before making a change.

You can use CCleaner, to remove the traces of the Git installation on your computer. When running the registry cleaner, do back up the registry when asking you to delete entries, just in case you need to restore them.

Or

If you just want to remove Git from the context menu, a link below explains on how to do this.

https://www.ghacks.net/2017/07/09/remove-windows-10-context-menu-bloat/